# CSS: Fluid layout - footer always at the bottom, and a fluid center

Tags: css

How would you do this:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Except with a fluid center (vertically stretched, height 100%)?

Comment: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/bottom-footer-demo.htm is the demo

Comment: Can you be more descriptive of what you want?  Fluid center horizontally and vertically?  Vertically stretched to the bottom of the content?  Height 100% of what?

Comment: I want the DIV in the middle of the page to allow for some elements inside it using width:100%

Comment: @DavidLawson Wasn’t my answer useful? It has been long since I answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a display:table; layout for the body or a wrapper, and giving the middle row a hundred percent height.

Like this.-

```
<body>
<div>
    <div id=head">head</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id=body">body</div>
</div>
<div id=head">
    <div id="foot">foot</div>
</div>
</body>
```

With the following CSS.

```
html, body
{
    height:100%;
}
body
{
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}
body > div
{
    display:table-row;
}
body > div > div
{
    display:table-cell;
}
#body
{
    height:100%;
}
```